# How do I disable the hiding of Safari buttons in iOS 15.6.1?

Tags: iphone, settings, mobile-safari

The Safari buttons some times hides themselves:
[image: shown]

Is there a way to disable the hiding?
[image: hidden]

Comment: They usually disappear to gain screen space as you scroll down. Scrolling up should make them reappear. Tapping the time at the top of the screen [once or twice depending on how you have your menus set] will quickly re-enable too. I know of no way to prevent this.

Comment: I work around it, just these sites (stack exchange) have review queue that you need to click on the button, wait for safari to shift / reduce the screen to put the bottom buttons on safari back, then click a second time at the new location. Lose about 5 seconds to double click two spots when if safari always had the nav up it’d be 0.5 second and only one click. Super frustrating interaction

Comment: I can imagine it's irritating. tbh I still use the old iOS app for SE if I'm on the road, which is bad enough. I cannot abide trying to use most web sites including this one through a 4" letter-box. ;) My main interaction with it is from the desktop.